# ios7 status bar overlaps toolbar when using container view

Tags: ios, statusbar, ios7

I´v read the posts regarding this issue but found nothing to work, I think it must be since I am using a toolbar and have the View Controller embedded in a container view. The status bar always overlaps. No matter if I try to replace the toolbar or set different settings in IB. It also seems that since it´s inside a container view, setting the inferred option does not work. I even tried putting two toolbars on top, but only this one shows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The status bar in iOS 7 is transparent, so if you want to have a look similar to that of iOS6, create a view of 20 pixels and add it inside your "container" view...

```
UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[containerViewController.view addSubview:statusBarView];
```

Then set the frame of your "contained" ViewController accordingly

```
containedViewController.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, itsCurrentHeight - 20);
```

This way the status bar should not overlap with your content anymore